# Russian texting shorthand for yes and no

Tags: сленг

On the wiki page for the Russian hockey player Evgeni Malkin, it says that he used to text "$" to agree to an invitation and "da" to decline. It is uncited, so I can't check the original interview. Is this likely to be true? I thought 'Da' mean yes?

The Wiki section in question:
"There are several stories in which teammates would text Malkin to go out to dinner and his responses would be "Da" or "$". The teammates had no idea what those responses meant, but when Malkin replied with "$" he would be at dinner and when he replied "Da" he would not show up. They surmised the $ meant yes and the Da meant no."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evgeni_Malkin

Comment: I read an article once about Russian and English texting. The author had an idea that the shorthands in Russian are not used because you can type twice as much letters simply by switching to latin characters (because of different encodings).

Answer (score 2):

> Malkin's friends say he is charming and funny, and the English is coming, slowly.  His buddies and teammates used to chuckle at his replies to their texts, which would usually consist of nothing but a "K", a "$"(they have no idea what that meant), or a "Da", the Russian word for yes.  Now, there are actual words in complete sentences.

http://www.tsn.ca/columnists/james_duthie/?id=272375

I also have absolutely no idea what "$" means. Short on cash? :)

Comment: @user2258 Maybe "K" is a shorthand for "Ok".

Comment: @Artemix Yep, that is common

Answer (score 0):

Well, while there are other words for "да" and "нет", I don't see how you can find any shorthand for words that are already 2/3 letters long short of writing д/н or +/-.

Malkin's behavior you've mentioned have nothing to do with Russian language and is some kind of his own peculiarity.

Comment: Well, in English you can just write "k" instead of "Ok". So it is possible to make short words even shorter.

Comment: @Artemix while it possible, in Russian de-facto, nobody writes `д` or `нт` or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

In Russian language you can use

yes = ага, угу

no = не

Comment: The question is about texting (sending SMS).